# Cutting tool edges not beveling

Tags: bevel

[image]I'm a Blender super noob that got tired of trying to figure this out on my own by watching over an hour of videos on this subject with no luck.  I've got an object (like a cube) that I created a simple cutting tool for (duplicate cube, but slightly smaller) that I successfully used as a cutting tool to make the original cube into a container (that has sides and a bottom, but no top).  When I try to bevel ALL of the edges, it doesn't bevel the inside edges including the inside edge of the container walls (i.e. none of the edges that the cutting tool was touching gets beveled).  Also, I see the container just fine in object mode but in edit mode it looks like a solid cube (with a solid top, no container walls).  What am I missing?

Comment: I assume by 'cutting tool' you mean using as the boolean tool? In Edit mode you will see the original object unless you Apply the Boolean Modifier (Ctrl-A while hovering over the modifier panel in Object mode. Similarly you can't bevel edges which have been cut by the modifier unless it's been applied first because the edges don't really exist.

Comment: @JohnEason You don't need to apply the _Boolean_ modifier to bevel the edges created by it. Since the question says "...try to bevel ALL of the edges, it doesn't bevel the inside edges" I guess they are visible, but only the outer edges are beveled. So presumably it's _Object Mode_, not _Edit Mode_, and a _Bevel_ modifier is used. Then it is only a matter of the order of modifiers. Idave: the modifiers work top to bottom, so if you want the inside edges to be beveled, you have to put the _Boolean_ modifier on top and the _Bevel_ modifier below.

Comment: True but he didn't actually say he was using a bevel modifier though. I assumed he was trying to manually bevel all the edges in Edit mode with the boolean Display modifier icon enabled and was confused as to why the bevel only worked on the outer edges. Some images in the question would have helped! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason Definitely, images would be helpful ;) Since he saw the inner edges not being beveled while in _Edit Mode_ there not even were inner edges for him, it seemed obvious to me that he used a _Bevel_ modifier first even before cutting the object, then came the _Boolean_, and when those edges did not get beveled he switched to _Edit Mode_ to try it manually. Idave: As you see, there are many ways to determine what could have gone wrong. So it is always best to explain in detail what you did and add screenshots of objects and modifiers to support your explanations.

Comment: I've always thought that it would be a good idea to pop up a window with brief suggestions for new users on how to ask a question when the 'Ask a Question' button is clicked. That would save a lot of our time asking for images or more details!

Comment: I'm also new to StackOverflow!  It wasn't clear where I should add my answers/comments to your questions, Add Comment or Edit original post.  First, I tried Add Comment but I got an error that I used too many characters, so then I put my comments in the Edit section of my original post, but I don't see them now after submitting the edit.  I've got a lot to learn!

Comment: I still need help here, but I'm not sure how to continue.  My reply to @JohnEason and Gordon Eason's questions (within my original post) is not showing up and the "Add comment" field isn't large enough for my response, so I'll post my response in pieces, in more comments...

Comment: I added a screenshot to my original post which will hopefully answer a few (maybe most) of your questions.  This was the state of my workflow when I made the original post (i.e. I didn’t move the Bevel modifier to the bottom after I read your posts, it was always there).  I’m not 100% sure I “applied” the Bevel modifier but hopefully the screenshot shows I did.  Maybe after I enter my data into the modifier I need to apply it, with Ctrl-A???  When I used the Bool Tool to make the cut I chose Brush Boolean -> Difference.  Maybe this is a key point?

Comment: FYI, I used this video as guide to do my cutting and beveling:   COMPLETE Beginners Guide to Hard Surface Modeling (Blender Tutorial) - YouTube, the cutting and beveling operations start at 11:01.  I watched this section of the video many time to make sure I got it correct, but my bevels don’t seem to be working like Josh’s do.  Also, it appears Josh is in Object mode the whole time (while cutting and beveling), so this is what I did.  I just happened to notice that in Edit mode I don’t see the walls of my container.  I just see a rectangular block.

Comment: I mentioned this in my original post thinking it might be a clue as to what I may have missed.  FYI, I realize my bevels must be very small because the walls of this container are only 2mm thick!  Maybe they are too small to bevel?  But this next potential problem is separate from getting all the edges beveled first, I believe.

Comment: Done.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Can anyone see this post?  I still need help but I'm not sure how to get it.  Maybe I need to make a new post on this issue?